# Relation between dash pot and spring in forces when extracting a transfer function

Tags: control, control-system, transfer-function, mechanical

If a spring load some energy and use it for opposing other forces, and a dash pot has a friction, physically the both shouldn't have the same force-displacement equation ?

In most of dash pots, we could find an inner spring right ?

Comment: Spring force is proportional to displacement; add a dashpot and you introduce a force proportional to velocity (derivative of displacement); add a mass and you introduce a force proportional to acceleration (derivative of velocity, and 2nd derivative of displacement). And these systems are, respectively, 0th order, 1st order and 2nd order. A similar relationship exists for resistor; inductor; capacitor.

Comment: ... derivative = multiply by s in Laplace TF.

Comment: I don't see how this is related to EE...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has nothing to do with EE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A spring stores energy, a dashpot dissipates energy, so without going into any more detail than that, you know they must have different equations.

The spring delivers a force proportional to the displacement.

A dashpot delivers a force proportional to the velocity, or the rate of change of displacement. In most dashpots, you'll find a fluid being forced through a small orifice as the piston moves.

---